# Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS keeps telling that a new release is available

Tags: upgrade

I have upgraded my Ubuntu VM from 13.10 to 14.04.2 LTS. When I log in, it keeps telling me that a new release "14.04.2 LTS" is available:

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.11.0-18-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/

Your Ubuntu release is not supported anymore.
For upgrade information, please visit:
http://www.ubuntu.com/releaseendoflife

New release '14.04.2 LTS' available.
Run 'do-release-upgrade' to upgrade to it.
```

I used `do-release-upgrade` to upgrade.

How do I get rid of this message?

Also, I was connected via SSH and after the installation it said it completed, but with errors, allthough I couldn't find any in the buffer of the PuTTY terminal. Where can I find the logs of the installation?

Comment: Run the do-release-upgrade command?

Comment: Why the downvote? As I said, I have run that command and I am now at 14.04.2 (at least that's what the welcome message says). But it also says that the exact same version is newly available. Also, when I log in using Xfce it prompts me a message that a new version "14.10" is available. But I want to keep the LTS version.